# Installing Ubuntu along with storage on a 64 GB flash drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I have a 64 GB flash drive that I would like to use for multiple purposes:
1) Storing files
2) Running Ubuntu (persistent live usb) off of.

I read on here that I need to create two partitions of my USB and install Ubuntu on the second partition because Windows can only read the first partition--so my data will go on partition 1.

However, I'm not given the option to install Ubuntu on a partition of my drive when I go into Startup Disk Creator. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the install media
2) Install gparted sudo apt-get install gparted
3) Connect the pendrive, open gparted and reduce the partition dedicated to Ubuntu. In the new space create a nfts. Windows will read seamlessly

Comment: Does this mean I can possibly put my windows system image on the first partition and ubuntu live cd on the second?

Comment: use the latest Ubuntu installer option.  Create a FAT or NTFS partition and an extended.  Within the extended create a ext4 and swap.  
Select the ext4 and install Ubuntu